# git --global switch related to one user or all user?

Tags: linux, git

Suppose I have two users A and B in my Linux system. I am logged in as user `A`. If i configure an option using the `--global` switch like this

```
git config --global user.name "my name"
```

Will this set option only for user A? Or it will affect both users: `A` and user `B`?

Comment: All users. That's what global means.

Comment: @sevenseacat not this time.

Comment: ooooh, I have learnt something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`--global` is the option to for configuring stuff for the current user. It stores data into you home directory in `~/.gitconfig` by default, or `./.config/git/config` if the file exists and `~/.gitconfig` does not.

`--system` is the option for all users, you probably need root access to use it and it stores data into `/etc/gitconfig`.

If you don't use any of them, that's the repo specific config going into `.git/config`.

See the [OPTIONS section of git config's documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_options) for details.

If there are conflicts for a certain parameter, the smaller scope config wins.

Answer (score 6):

`--global` is user level. It writes to `$HOME/.gitconfig`.

`--system` is global for the whole operating system. It writes to `$(prefix)/etc/.gitconfig`.

`man git config` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

`--global` only affects the `.gitconfig` file under the current user home directory, so it will only apply to user A but not user B.

For all users, there is `--system` option.

```
--global
    For writing options: write to global ~/.gitconfig file rather than the repository .git/config.

    For reading options: read only from global ~/.gitconfig rather than from all available files.


--system
    For writing options: write to system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather than the repository .git/config.

    For reading options: read only from system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig rather than from all available files.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Git documentation, Git uses a series of configuration files to determine non-default behavior that you may want. The first place Git looks for these values is in an /etc/gitconfig file, which contains values for every user on the system and all of their repositories. If you pass the option --system to git config, it reads and writes from this file specifically.

**The next place Git looks is the** ~/.gitconfig **file, which is specific to each user.** You can make Git read and write to this file by passing the --global option.

Finally, Git looks for configuration values in the config file in the Git directory (.git/config) of whatever repository you’re currently using. These values are specific to that single repository. Each level overwrites values in the previous level, so values in .git/config trump those in /etc/gitconfig, for instance.

So by doing

```
   git config --global user.name "my name"
```

it changes the settings/configurations only for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

It's about the global settings for the current user (the one you're logged in as)